# How to get OS X out of a strange debug mode

Tags: macos, voiceover

My two year old loves banging on the keyboard of my iMac and occasionally  discovers strange features that I've never seen before.

Most recently he has enabled what appears to be some kind of debug mode where there is a black box just above and to the left of the dock containing current windowing event info. I'll post a screengrab when I've got enough reputation to do so.

[image: screen grab]
, and[image: another with info from Aperture]

This debug mode is also making apps such as my browser unusable as it tends to scroll back to the top of pages at regular intervals.

Does anyone know how to switch this off?

Another thing he managed to do was to create an empty folder on the desktop with the name "Time Machine", i.e. exactly the name of a volume on the desktop (he certainly didn't type that). It doesn't sound a particularly useful feature but I'd be interested to know how he did it.

Comment: There's no prohibition on naming a folder the same as a volume. If an icon is selected, the key sequence ⌘C, ⌘⇧N, ⌘V will create a folder with the same name. I don't recognize your “debug mode” — have you checked whether it's a running application? That sounds like something a newer version of Quartz Debug than I've seen might do.

Comment: Dont worry about the rep, post it to imageshack or something and we will reupload it, I am interested to see this "windowing info", Kevin seems like he is on the right track.

Comment: THanks for the answers so far. Regarding the debug mode, this is specific to a single user account, i.e. not machine-wide and also is retained after a restart, i.e. it much be persisted somewhere. It is there even when there aren't any apps running (other than the dock of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kid managed to activate VoiceOver. To turn it if, go to Preferences/Accessibility (or try <kbd>Command-F5</kbd> first)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, that is it. Nothing to do with debugging at all. It now turns out that my wife had turned the volume right down as she didn't know how to switch if off.

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe it's time to give him an account on her own to play with...